# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL using Cloud Shell with SSL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I've set up a PostgreSQL instance on Google Cloud SQL and have set it up now to only allow SSL connections. I'm able to connect from my workstation via psql and from some apps like R Studio.

However I'm trying to connect via the GCloud Shell and don't seem to see any options to connect with SSL. There are [options to manage certifications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance) and I've created another client key and downloaded the files for it in my cloud shell account, I just don't see options for using them to make a connection. Without it just tells me there isn't an HBA for a "No SSL" connection.

Here is what I see (some things obfuscated):

```
don@cloudshell:~ (xxx)$ gcloud sql connect foo --user=postgres
Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
Connecting to database with SQL user [postgres].Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "a.b.c.d", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Cloud SQL GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell):

> Cloud Shell connections do not support SSL. Connections from Cloud
>   Shell fail if the instance is configured to accept only SSL
>   connections.

Comment: OK thanks. In my defense, that text only exists on the MySQL version of that document. Click on the PostgreSQL version and it doesn't mention the cloud shell limitation.

Marked as answered.

Comment: I've submitted feedback on that documentation page about the line missing for the PostgreSQL side. Thanks again.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I was about to report this miss in the docs, but as you've already done it, thanks!

Comment: Everything Google does is broken.

Comment: From the docs: The gcloud sql connect command does not support connecting to a Cloud SQL instance using private IP, or using SSL/TLS. To connect with encryption, install and use the proxy in the Cloud Shell:

Install the proxy (Linux 64-bit) in the /home/USER directory.
Start the proxy, using Cloud SDK authentication:
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:5432 &
Connect to the database by using the TCP connection:

psql -U USERNAME --host=127.0.0.1